# sbt run won't find external libraries

Tags: sql-server, scala, dependencies, sbt

I have `mssql` as an external library defined like this in my `build.sbt`.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.2",
  "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.4.1.jre8"
)
```

Now, in order to run my main object, I do the following

1. `sbt`
2. `run`
3. choose the main object

Now, it seems however, that the driver, i.e. the library cannot be found.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbc
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

I assume it's simply not included in the class path. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Edit: I use the following way to acquire a database connection.

```
object DatabaseUtils {
  private val cfg: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("database")
  def db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = cfg.db
}
```

With this configuration

```
database = {
 profile = "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile$"
 db {
  host = "<IP>"
  port = <port>
  databaseName = "<dbname>"

  url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"${database.db.host}":"${database.db.port}";databaseName="${database.db.databaseName}
  user = "<user>"
  password = "<pass>"
 }
}
```

Comment: add your database configuration / the sbt configuration looks fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the Database Driver. From the [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/database.html):

```
tsql {
  driver = "slick.driver.H2Driver$"
  db {
    connectionPool = disabled
    driver = "org.h2.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:tsql1;INIT=runscript from 'src/main/resources/create-schema.sql'"
  }
}
```

I don't use *Slick*, in our project, the driver for MSSQL is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`